# Ask user for input and scan to a certain file and output results (with duplicates)

Tags: bash, shell, unix, duplicates, unique

I need to prompt the user to enter a name of a class that comes from CSV file:

```
Computer,Course 1,This course is taught by Dr. Chen
Information technology,Course 2,This course is taught by Dr. Weiss
Database,Course 3,This course is taught by Dr. Gonzalas
Algorithm,Course 4,This course is taught by Dr. Sanabria
Computer,Course 5,This course is taught by Dr. Sun
Data mining,Course 6,This course is taught by Dr. Li
Algorithm,Course 8,This course is taught by Dr. Xue
```

The user will enter one of the items in Column 1. As you can see, there are duplicates. There needs to be a way to prompt the user to clarify which class he is going to be requesting information about, and then continue with the selection.

How can I do that?

Comment: What exactly is the question?

Comment: Have you written any code so far?  Please note that StackOverflow is not a free code writing service.

Comment: I suggest to take a look at bash‘s `read` command: `help read`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please take into consideration that this is just a draft, which runs on my system and has not been tested on other

```
#!/bin/bash

IFS=$"\n"

# Read user input
read -p "Type a name of class: " class

# Results in two views - entries count and entries content
entries_cnt=`cat ./tst.csv | cut -d',' -f1 | grep -cw "$class"`
entries_nfo=$(cat tst.csv | awk -v class=$class -F"," '{if ($1 ~ class) print $0 }')

# If one entry founded
if [ "$entries_cnt" == "1" ] ; then
    echo 'Entry founded:'
    echo $entries_nfo

# If entry not founded
elif [ "$entries_cnt" \< "1" ] ; then
    echo 'Entry not found'

# If founded more than 1 entry
else
    echo 'Founded more than 1 entry:'
    echo $entries_nfo;
    echo 'Available courses:'
    echo $entries_nfo | cut -d',' -f2

    # Read user input
    read -p 'Input course: ' course
    echo $entries_nfo | awk -v course=$course -F"," '{if ($2 ~ course) print $0 }'
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to work a lot of it out, with some of the combine help you all put. This is what I was able to do:

```
#!/bin/sh
#Start your code from here


# Clear page and enter variables: date, files, etc.
clear
template=Template.email
d=$(date +%m-%d-%Y)

grep '[^[:blank:]]' < Dictionary.data > temp.csv
awk 'NR > 2 {print}' < temp.csv > temp2.csv

# Welcome message and display catalog/dictionary
echo "Hello and welcome to the Spring Term of 2017"
echo "Below are the classes available to you to enroll in."
echo "Select a course and we will email you further information"
echo "about the class."
echo "======================================================"

# Read file
while IFS=, read col1 col2 col3
do
    echo "$col1"
done < temp2.csv

# Ask for student email and class selection
echo ""
echo "Please enter your email: "
read email

echo "Please pick a class: "
read course

    # Open case switch 
    case $course in

        # Computer case
        "Computer")

            # Advise user about duplicates
            echo "There are two Computer courses with the same name. Please pick the one you like: "
            echo "1) Course 1 taught by Dr. Chen"
            echo "2) Course 5 taught by Dr. Sun"
            read detail

            # Ask user to pick which class he/she wants
            case $detail in

                # Display message and email user desciptions
                1)
                    echo "We have emailed you the course description. Thank you!"

                    sed -e "s/_CourseNumber_/Course 1/g" -e "s/__Description__/This course is taught by Dr. Chen/g" -e "s/_Date_/$d/g" Template.email | mail -s 'Information about your class' $email
                    ;;

                2)
                    echo "We have emailed you the course description. Thank you!"

                    sed -e "s/_CourseNumber_/Course 5/g" -e "s/__Description__/This course is taught by Dr. Sun/g" -e "s/_Date_/$d/g" Template.email | mail -s 'Information about your class' $email
                    ;;

                *) 

                    # Incorrect input
                    echo "Sorry that was not a correct choice."
                    break;;
            esac

            ;;

        # IT case   
        "Information technology")

            # Display message and email user desciptions
            echo "We have emailed you the course description. Thank you!"

            sed -e "s/_CourseNumber_/Course 2/g" -e "s/__Description__/This course is taught by Dr. Weiss/g" -e "s/_Date_/$d/g" Template.email | mail -s 'Information about your class' $email
            ;;

        # Database case
        "Database")

            # Display message and email user desciptions
            echo "We have emailed you the course description. Thank you!"

            sed -e "s/_CourseNumber_/Course 2/g" -e "s/__Description__/This course is taught by Dr. Weiss/g" -e "s/_Date_/$d/g" Template.email | mail -s 'Information about your class' $email
            ;;

        #Algorithm case
        "Algorithm")

            # Display message and email user desciptions
            echo "There are two Algorithm courses with the same name. Please pick the one you like: "
            echo "1) This course is taught by Dr. Sanabria"
            echo "2) This course is taught by Dr. Xue"
            read detail

            # Ask user to pick which class he/she wants
            case $detail in

                # Display message and email user desciptions
                1)
                    echo "We have emailed you the course description. Thank you!"

                    sed -e "s/_CourseNumber_/Course 4/g" -e "s/__Description__/This course is taught by Dr. Sanabria/g" -e "s/_Date_/$d/g" Template.email | mail -s 'Information about your class' $email
                    ;;

                2)
                    echo "We have emailed you the course description. Thank you!"

                    sed -e "s/_CourseNumber_/Course 8/g" -e "s/__Description__/This course is taught by Dr. Xue/g" -e "s/_Date_/$d/g" Template.email | mail -s 'Information about your class' $email
                    ;;

                *) 

                    # Incorrect input
                    echo "Sorry that was not a correct choice."
                    break;;
            esac

            ;;

        # Data Mining case
        "Data mining")

            # Display message and email user desciptions
            echo "We have emailed you the course description. Thank you!"

            sed -e "s/_CourseNumber_/Course 6/g" -e "s/__Description__/This course is taught by Dr. Li/g" -e "s/_Date_/$d/g" Template.email | mail -s 'Information about your class' $email
            ;;

        *) 

            # Incorrect input
            echo "Sorry that was not a correct choice.";;

    esac

    rm temp.csv
    rm temp2.csv
# End of file
```